# Control the parameter values that can be sent to a function in different class

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums

So I have a button which on being clicked exports a selected asset(jpgs,svgs,jsos,etc). Now I have a different class(export class) which handles the exporting logic. What I want to achieve is a generic method in my export class, which handles all exports. So I need to send in as parameters the type of file I want to export. I don't want to use integers or strings, as that makes my code breakable. I want to use an enum, but don't know how to make an enum which is accessible in both the classes. Can someone please give me the details on how to go about doing this.

```
-(void)exportAsset: filePath typeOfAsset:(customEnumType*)
```

I want a similar function, but I don't no how to create an enum which is accessible in both the classes, i.e, the details of how to do this. Please help. Sorry for any newbie mistakes. Also thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the typedef enum code block in the header (.h) file of one of your classes, and import this file to the other class by using this statement:

```
#import "[File Name].h"
```

Answer (score 0):

you should put enum in common header file

Example of enum:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, PRESENT){

PRESENT_WITH_PUSH = 1,
PRESENT_WITH_MODEL = 2,
PRESENT_WITH_PUSH_EDIT = 3};
```

OR

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, PRESENT){

PRESENT_WITH_PUSH = 0,
PRESENT_WITH_MODEL,
PRESENT_WITH_PUSH_EDIT
};
```